# Text in span disappear in Firefox using flex and writing-mode

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

I have to show a short paragraph of Japanese characters centering both horizontally and vertically. I use this technique, and it worked well on Google Chrome, but not on Firefox.

```css
// div {
//    width: 300px;
//    height: 300px;
//    background: wheat;
// }

// span {
//    writing-mode: tb-rl;
//    display: flex;
//    justify-content: center;
//    align-items: center;
//    width: 100%;
//    height: 100%;
// }

div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: wheat;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

span {
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,0);
    left:initial;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>テスト<br>テスト<br>テスト</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't add the solution to your question, post it as a self answer

Comment: @LGSon I've posted a new post for my answer.

Comment: Thanks....upvoted :)

Comment: If you incorporate your solution into your question, try to be clear that that is what you are doing. Say something like "I like this solution but have questions about it". I notice you do this in your answer, but it is still confusing that this is not in the question. The comments do not help, as they do not explain anything.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @fen1x a lot for your answer. But still there are a lot of problems in your solution. (See updated version above). Finally, the best thing for this situation is using `position: absolute` instead of `display: flex`. This will also work well on both IE 11 and IE Edge.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: wheat;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  writing-mode: tb-rl;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>テストテスト<br>テストテストテスト<br>テスト</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's a [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1223180).

This can avoided by using another centering method for Firefox (though, it's a bit hacky):

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: wheat;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

span {
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,0);
    left:initial;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>テスト</span>
</div>
```